# Correct implementation for nested scrolling parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing a custom `DrawerLayout` and I want to support nested scrolling in it. For example, I need to support a `ListView` in the bottom side drawer.

Everything else is working fine, except that once the `Listview` has scrolled all the way to its bottom, trying to scroll up any further doesn't show the edge-glow/gradient that is normally visible when the `Listview` is not inside my custom `DrawerLayout`.

My DrawerLayout implements NestedeSCrollingParent and has all the methods implemented. I suspect the issue has something to do with my implementation of the following 2 methods.
For the purpose of testing, I am not consuming any scroll in the DrawerLayout.

Could anyone tell me with this implementation, why I couldn't see the edge-glow/gradient in the Listview that is added in this DrawerLayout?

```
@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    consumed[0] = consumed[1] = 0;
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    int[] consumed = new int[2];
    dispatchNestedScroll(consumed[0], consumed[1], dxUnconsumed-consumed[0], dyUnconsumed-consumed[1], null);
}
```

[image]

Comment: edge-glow/gradient?? you better do a youtube vid to show what happens or add some screenshots in your Q

Comment: please add xml and java files.